# ProxyPass with port in url

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, port, virtualhost, mod-proxy

I have such a virtual host on apache:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.250.54:80>
    ServerName host-test
    ProxyPass / http://backend-host
    ProxyPassReverse / http://backend-host
</VirtualHost>
```

When I type

```
curl host-test
```

it works, it shows me welcome page from the backend host.

When I type

```
curl host-test:9080
```

it shows me (7) couldn't connect to host.

I would like to make redirection from host-test:9080 to host-test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I had to create similar virtual host on port 9080 and to set

```
Listen 9080
```